# Galois group of $x^4+tx+t\in F(t)[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory, galois-theory, irreducible-polynomials

> Let $F$ be a field of characteristic $\operatorname{char}(F)\ne2$. Prove that the polynomial $f(x)=x^4+tx+t\in F(t)[x]$ is irreduciable, and find its Galois group.

Proving that the polynomial is rather simple, using the [generalized Eisenstein criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein%27s_criterion#Generalization), taking the ideal $\mathfrak{p}=(t)\in F[t]$ (as $f$ is monic, it will be irreducible in $F(t)[x]$ from Gauss's lemma).

 The discriminant is $\Delta_x=-27t^4+256t^3$, the root of which is not an element of $F(t)$. Can I deduce that $\operatorname{Gal}(f)\cong S_4$?

Comment: You can deduce that the Galois group is a transitive subgroup of $S_4$ which is not contained in $A_4$. I reckon there are three of them, up to conjugacy. Is the cubic resolvent of $f$ irreducible?